# The problem of saving data in the database and closing the program quickly after execution

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I have a layout that has two EDITETEXT and they should be filled and saved in the database by pressing the save button

Everything is correct, but when I write the button code, the program runs
and quickly exits the program

***(And that there is no mistake)***

If I want to say complete, it means: everything is correct until I want to use the database :|

code main activity:

```
enter codeclass MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var adapter: Adapter
private lateinit var layoutManger:LinearLayoutManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   buttonsave.setOnClickListener {
        var dbmanger= DBmanager(this)
        var values = ContentValues()
        values.put("Title",editTextTitle.text.toString())
        values.put("Desc",editTextdesc.text.toString())
        val ID= dbmanger .Insert (values)
        if (ID > 0 ){
            Toast.makeText(this, "یــادادشــت جـــدیِـد ذخـیره شـــد!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, " خطــا در ذخـیره یــادادشــت !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    layoutManger = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    adapter = Adapter()
    val list = ArrayList<Model>()
    list.apply {
        add(Model("fatemeh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("reyhaneh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("bahareh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("abolfazl", "chamani fard"))
    }
    adapter.setList(list)
    list_main.layoutManager=layoutManger
    list_main.adapter=adapter


}
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when(item.itemId)
    {
        R.id.menuItemNew->{
        var intent=Intent(this,addnoteactivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

code button:

```
enter cod   buttonsave.setOnClickListener {
        var dbmanger= DBmanager(this)
        var values = ContentValues()
        values.put("Title",editTextTitle.text.toString())
        values.put("Desc",editTextdesc.text.toString())
        val ID= dbmanger .Insert (values)
        if (ID > 0 ){
            Toast.makeText(this, "یــادادشــت جـــدیِـد ذخـیره شـــد!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, " خطــا در ذخـیره یــادادشــت !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

code database:

```
enter code hclass DBmanager {
val dbName="notesDB"
val dbTable="tblNotes"
val colID="ID"
val colTitle="Title"
val colDesc="Desc"
val dbVersion=1
val sqlCreateTable="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbTable + " ("+ colID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+ colTitle +" TEXT,"+ colDesc +" TEXT);"

var sqlDB:SQLiteDatabase ?= null
constructor (context: Context){
val db =DatabaseHelper(context)
    sqlDB=db.writableDatabase
}
inner class DatabaseHelper :SQLiteOpenHelper {
    var context:Context ?= null
    constructor(context: Context):super(context,dbName,null,dbVersion){
        this.context=context

    }
    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    p0 !!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
        Toast.makeText(context, "دیتا بیس ایجاد شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
    p0 !!.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbTable)
    }
}

fun Insert(values:ContentValues):Long{
val ID=sqlDB!!.insert(dbTable,"",values)
    return ID
}
```

}

**Help me please**

***Kotlin language***

These are displayed in logcat:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2022-07-17 09:20:46.820 7916-7916/com.example.data420tir E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.data420tir, PID: 7916
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.data420tir/com.example.data420tir.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.buttonsave) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3897)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.buttonsave) must not be null
        at com.example.data420tir.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3870)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055) 
2022-07-17 09:20:46.834 7916-7916/com.example.data420tir I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7916 SIG: 9
```

***And one question: what does Android aip 31 mean?***

Comment: Your code exits quickly because it is throwing an exception. Have a look at the logcat, copy the exception & edit your post to include it

Comment: I applied the changes you said, but the answer is the same as before

Comment: You did? Where?

Comment: I added the logcat code and what android api 31 means؟

Answer (score 1):

Add layout file before any action or initialization of widget.

It should be like

```
  MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //Your code
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 val buttonsave:Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonsave)
          buttonsave.setOnClickListener {
       //Your code
        }
    //Your code
    }
```

Comment: @F.chamani before layout initialization you cant initialize and button or other Widgets. If you will try that you will get null exception and app get crash same time because app not getting your button id from layout .

Comment: @F.chamani check this official documentation for your reference -https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: just add your  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) line after  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) and remove from below

Comment: I applied the changes you said, but the answer is the same as before

Comment: What @SandeshKhutalSaheb is telling you is correct. If you have made their suggested change AND you are still having the SAME issue then that means that buttonsave does not exist in the layout file 'activity_main'